# Bash variable expansion

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do some variable expansion in bash but somehow the result is truncated/rotated. Here's a sample my code:

```
x="no-cabac,level=3,ref=3,bframes=0,subme=0,weightp=0"
tts="{$x}"
echo $tts
```

This prints: `}no-cabac,level=3,ref=3,bframes=0,subme=0,weightp=0`

I expected: `{no-cabac,level=3,ref=3,bframes=0,subme=0,weightp=0}`

If I change tts to `tts=abc{$x}qwe` the output is `}qweno-cabac,level=3,ref=3,bframes=0,subme=0,weightp=0`

I tried escaping the braces and removing the quotes, still doesn't work. I know there's something that has to be escaped but I can't figure out what.

`bash --version` output: `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(21)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)`

Comment: That works fine for me with `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting your `$x` from somewhere else, and it has a `\r` at the end. Try:

```
tts="{${x/$'\r'/}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had my script file with CRLFs, therefore the extra \r :-/

Comment: BTW I converted to LF and the original script worked just fine.

Comment: Just a diagnostic tip: pipe a variable value (or any string) to `| od -a` to see a character-by-character representation of it with _whitespace and control characters showing with symbolic names_. For instance, a `\r` shows as `cr`, `\n` as `nl`, `\t` as `ht`.